# Grant S3 bucket access to all principals in organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

#### Scenario:

I have 3 AWS root accounts in the same organization.

1. admin@mydomain.com
2. user1@mydomain.com
3. user2@mydomain.com

`user1` created an S3 bucket `B1`. I want `user2` and `admin` to be able to see and browse `B1` on their own S3 dashboard. Is this possible? What policy(policies) that I need to create? Where do I create these policies and how to create them?

**The original question has been edited. Some answers below might not be relevant any more

Comment: Your policy is not a bucket policy. Its missing `Principal` which is required for bucket policy. So you want to create bucket policy or regular IAM policy?

Comment: I want other people in my organization to be able to browse/use s3 buckets (on aws s3 dashboard) created by my account. Which policy would that be?

Comment: @OshMansor for this to work you need both identity policy and resource policy allowing , and result of both of them should be allow. [Identity-based policies and resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html).In your case one resource policy(s3 bucket) and identity policy would be for the people who want to access the bucket and both should allow whichever action you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, I cannot do the S3 bucket console sharing between root users. I've finally managed to share the bucket created by `user1` with an IAM user.

### Steps for Root User

1. Login into AWS console and go to IAM
2. Create group
3. Create IAM policy i.e. allowing S3 full access (see below)
4. Attach policy to group
5. Create IAM user
6. For Access type choose AWS Management Console access
7. Add user to the group you created in step 1
8. Follow through until you click on create user button

#### IAM Policy

```json
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "s3:*",
         "Resource": "*",
         "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
               "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-xxxvvvwww8"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

### EDIT:

After rigorous trial & error testing, it seems that we don't even need bucket policy for this to work. I've removed the bucket policy and it all still works!

### Steps for IAM User

1. Log into AWS console as IAM user
2. Go to S3 console. You should be able to see and browse all buckets and objects created by all organization members

#### Note

Your IAM user would not be able to see the bucket listed on its S3 console dashboard. That shared bucket can only be accessed through direct link. So your root user must provide the URL i.e. `https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/bucket1/` to your IAM user

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is add `Principal: "*"` to the policy. This opens access to anyone, but the condition will limit it to the org.

Comment: After trying the suggestions in comments from other user. I realize my original post is for IAM policy. I'm editing my question with new information as I still unable to share bucket dashboard with other user of my organization